# Can unlist(strsplit(...)) produce the same result as gsub(...)?

Tags: r

In my SO activities, I find that many R users use `strsplit()` for text manipulation even when there is no actual splitting happening in the result.  That being said, here's my question:

Take the following character vector `x`:

```
> x <- c("1500 2", "1500 1", "1510 2", "1510 1", "1520 2")
```

I can extract the final digit in each string with a regular expression and `gsub()`

```
> gsub(".*\\s", "", x)
# [1] "2" "1" "2" "1" "2"
```

I can also do it with `strsplit()`.  However, because of the algorithm of `strsplit()` (noted at the bottom of this post), a `""` is placed in front of each match.

```
> unlist(strsplit(x, ".*\\s"))
# [1] ""  "2" ""  "1" ""  "2" ""  "1" ""  "2"
```

Those `""` strings can be removed easily by calling `nzchar()` on the result above. And of course I could write a function to do it all with `strsplit()` and `nzchar()`.

```
> f <- function(x, pattern)
  {
      y <- unlist(strsplit(x, pattern))
      y[nzchar(y)]
  }
> f(x, ".*\\s")
# [1] "2" "1" "2" "1" "2"
```

Since `strsplit()` accepts a regular expression in its `split` argument, I figured it might be possible to get the same result from `unlist(strsplit(...))` as I get fom `gsub(...)`. Does anyone know of a way to do this, or if it's possible at all?

**Note :** from `?strsplit`

> The algorithm applied to each input string ... means that if there is a match at the beginning of a (non-empty) string, the first element of the output is "", but if there is a match at the end of the string, the output is the same as with the match removed. Invalid inputs in the current locale are warned about up to 5 times.

Comment: For this specific example I would use `sapply(strsplit(x," "), '[', 2)` or `regmatches(x,regexpr("\\d$", x))`. Is there a reason you want to use strsplit just to extract the last element (ie when you're not really splitting anything?)

Comment: @MrFlick, I added a sentence to hopefully clarify that a bit.

Comment: I'm not sure that clears things up for me. The goal of `strsplit` is to split a string into different parts. When you split by `.*\\s`, that matches everything up to and including the space. Do you get everything before that (which is the empty string) and everything after (the last digit). It uses regular expressions very differently that `gsub` and just because they both accept regular expressions doesn't mean the have the same behavior. It would be better to use the `regexpr` function as I did above if you're not really interested in splitting anything,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you pointed in the definction of `strsplit`, the reason you get empty string is :

> if there is a match at the beginning of a (non-empty) string, the
>   first element of the output is ""

If you don't want to call `nzchar` at th end , and still use `strsplit`, you can insert a dummy character:

```
res <- unlist(strsplit(paste0('#',x),'\\d{4} '))
res[res !="#"]

[1] "2" "1" "2" "1" "2"
```

but I think here it is better to substitute no needed character using `sub` ( not `gsub`):

```
sub('\\d{4} ','',x)
```